# Change account settings in Outlook 2010 using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook-2010

I have a large number of forwarding email addresses which are all set to forward to the same email account. I find this is useful because if a business is hacked and my email address is stolen then I only have the change the email address for that business. For example, "amazon@mydomain.com", "ebay@mydomain.com" and "facebook@mydomain.com" would all be forwarded to "mailbox@mydomain.com".

When I want to send an email to the business, I have to go into Outlook and change the account set up to have the forwarding email address as the email address. I find this a nuisance. I know I can change who the email is from when I write it, but then the recipient sees "J Smith  on behalf of newaddress@mydomain.com". I would rather it just showed the address I am using in the from field, as it does if I go into the account set up and change the email address there.

It would be nice to have a macro set up which asked me which email address I wanted to use and then sent the email for me. I have looked up how to change email account details in VBA, but it looks as if the details are all read-only. Is there a way to change my "from" email address cleanly? Or even setting up a new email account in VBA and deleting it immediately after sending it?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a userform with a combobox and a button on it. Load all your available accounts into the combobox to be able to select from it:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim acc As Account

For Each acc In ThisOutlookSession.Session.Accounts

    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem acc.UserName
Next acc
End Sub
```

Then add some code to the button that selects the proper account:

```
Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set objApp = ThisOutlookSession.Application

Set objMail = objApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objMail

    .To = "lala@lala.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Test"
    .Body = "Test"

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To ThisOutlookSession.Session.Accounts.Count Step 1

        If ThisOutlookSession.Session.Accounts.Item(i).UserName = Me.ComboBox1.Value Then

            .SendUsingAccount = ThisOutlookSession.Session.Accounts.Item(i)
        End If
    Next i

    .Display
End With
```

Maybe there is an event that is called when you are creating a new email, otherwise you have to add a button or something to bring the form up.

Comment: Thanks gizlmeier, but I'm afraid this wouldn't work. I have so many forwarding addresses that I don't want to set up an Outlook account for each of them. What I want to do is change an existing account to contain the email address that I want the message to be from. Then when I send a message to a different business, I will change the same account again, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem and ended up being able to solve it by installing Outlook Redemption and using the following script...

```
                ' Redemption code below. Must install Redemption to work.
                ' http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#14

                Dim sItem, Tag
                Set sItem = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeMailItem")
                sItem.Item = oMailItem
                Tag = sItem.GetIDsFromNames("{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", "From")
                Tag = Tag Or &H1E     'the type is PT_STRING8
                sItem.Fields(Tag) = GetHashedReply(oMailItem)
                Tag = sItem.GetIDsFromNames("{00020386-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", "Sender")
                Tag = Tag Or &H1E     'the type is PT_STRING8
                sItem.Fields(Tag) = GetHashedReply(oMailItem)
                sItem.Subject = sItem.Subject  'to trick Outlook into thinking that something has changed
                sItem.Save
```

...where oMailItem is a normal Outlook MailItem that you can get with CreateItem() or get passed to you in the ItemSend() parameters.